# Combine SELECT statements. Help Needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following two `T-SQL` statements that I really need to combine:

```
    SELECT Aircraft.Id AS AircraftID, AircraftManufacturers.Name, AircraftModels.ModelName, 
    Aircraft.ModelSuffix, Aircraft.ImageFileName, Aircraft.Year, Aircraft.SerialNo, 
    Locations.DescriptionForSite, Aircraft.Description, Aircraft.Description2, 
    Aircraft.InfoWebAddress, Aircraft.ImageDescription, Advertisers.Id AS AdvertisersID, 
    Advertisers.Name AS AdvertisersName, Aircraft.AircraftDataId, Aircraft.ForSale, Aircraft.ForLease, 
    Aircraft.TTAF, Aircraft.ReSend, Aircraft.ReSendReason, Aircraft.Registration, Aircraft.AdType,
    Aircraft.HasAlternateImage, Aircraft.AlternateImageDescription, 
    Aircraft.Price, AircraftModels.AircraftType, Advertisers.CurrentEMagLink, Aircraft.CurrentEMagLink, 
    Aircraft.Email, Aircraft.IsSold, Aircraft.SoldDate, Aircraft.DateAdded, Aircraft.ExtendedDetails, 
    Aircraft.LastUpdateDate, Aircraft.ImageCount, Aircraft.ContactTelephone, AircraftModels.id, Advertisers.IsPremiumAdvertiser,
    Aircraft.Location, Advertisers.ContactTelephone As AdvertisersTelephone, Aircraft.LastUpdateDate, Aircraft.EndDate, Aircraft.VideoLink
    FROM (((Aircraft 
    INNER JOIN Advertisers ON Aircraft.AdvertiserId = Advertisers.Id) 
    INNER JOIN AircraftModels ON Aircraft.AircraftModelId = AircraftModels.Id) 
    INNER JOIN AircraftManufacturers ON AircraftModels.ManufacturerId = AircraftManufacturers.Id) 
    INNER JOIN Locations ON Aircraft.LocationId = Locations.Id
    JOIN iter$simple_intlist_to_tbl(@ids) i ON AircraftModels.id = i.number
    WHERE (Aircraft.IsActive=1 AND Advertisers.IsActive=1 AND (Aircraft.EndDate>=@Date OR Aircraft.EndDate Is Null) AND Locations.DescriptionForSite LIKE @Location)
    OR (Advertisers.IsActive=1 AND Aircraft.IsSold=1 AND Aircraft.SoldDate>=@Date2 AND Locations.DescriptionForSite LIKE @Location)
    ORDER BY Advertisers.IsPremiumAdvertiser ASC, Aircraft.DateAdded DESC, Aircraft.ListPosition DESC, 
    Aircraft.LastUpdateDate, AircraftManufacturers.Name, AircraftModels.ModelName, Aircraft.ModelSuffix, 
    Aircraft.Id DESC
```

and

```
    SELECT TOP (1) dbo.Addresses.Email, dbo.Addresses.Contact, dbo.Addresses.Telephone1
    FROM dbo.AdvertiserAddressLink 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Addresses ON dbo.AdvertiserAddressLink.AddressId = dbo.Addresses.Id
    WHERE (dbo.AdvertiserAddressLink.AdvertiserId = 'AdvertisersID') <--see above 
    AND (dbo.Addresses.AddressType = 1 OR dbo.Addresses.AddressType = 0)
    ORDER BY dbo.Addresses.AddressType DESC, dbo.Addresses.Sequence
```

Comment: You want to combine them how/into what?

Comment: Have you ever considered using short aliases for tables?

Comment: You can look into the `APPLY` operator for this.

Comment: @JNK 'code' dbo.AdvertiserAddressLink.AdvertiserId = 'AdvertisersID' 'code' 'AdvertisersID is a value of the first SELECT statement.

Comment: @JNK One statement rather than two... as in combine them. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to do `TOP 1` in the second query based on a correlated parameter from the first?

You can use `APPLY` for this.

A simple example.

```
SELECT t.name, ca.name
FROM sys.tables t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM sys.columns c 
             WHERE c.object_id=t.object_id 
             ORDER BY name) ca
```

Comment: Thanks for that, could you possibly ellaborate a bit please.